# Has the phrase "in principal" ever been used to mean "in chief"?

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests

*I should make clear before I begin that I fully understand the distinction between "principal" and "principle", and any answerers need not explain the difference between the two in their answers.*

---

I'm in the process of building a fictional world, and, for reasons I won't go into here, I need more general officer ranks than the standard three to five. I want to retain the British titles - Major General, Lieutenant General, General - and so my solution is to add more ranks in between. I find adding the word "Brevet" to the front of these titles to be a satisfying way of indicating a slightly less important version thereof, as in Brevet Major General, and there is some historical precedence for this. (I know that, historically, a brevet rank was by definition not a substantive rank, but, for the purposes of my fictional world, that's a constraint we can ignore.)

**But what's an elegant way of expressing a slightly *more* important version of a given rank?** Senior Major General just sounds like corporate babble. Major General in Chief is the sort of thing I want, but it gives the impression that any given Major General in Chief is the *only* Major General in Chief, and thus has to be rejected. Major General in Ordinary does not sound grand enough. I really like **Major General in Principal**, but I can't convince myself that "in principal" is a legitimate English phrase.

I've googled "in principal" and varitions thereon, but all I get is pages mispelling "in principle", pages which concatenate "in" and "principal" but not as a phrase, and pages explaining why "in principal" is an incorrect variant of "in principle". **Is "in principal" a legitimate English phrase?** Has it ever been used by the army, the legal profession, or by some other state body?

Finally, I would gladly read any suggested alternatives to "in principal" in this context.

Comment: But in a work of fiction about an imaginary world, with imaginary military titles and ranks, the author commands.

Comment: @Mari-LouA That's a fair point, but I still feel that it would be good to be as authentic to the culture I'm borrowing from as possible. The very bad attempts at Latin in Warhammer 40,000 drive me round the bend!

Comment: Look to religion... pope, archbishop, cardinal, prelate, priest...

Answer (score 1):

Actually ***[In principal](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/in_principal)*** appears to be a

> misspelling  of “in principle.”

(Wiktionary)

There is no evidence in [Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20principal&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20principal%3B%2Cc0) that the expression has ever been used with the meaning of “in chief”.

Comment: @TomHosker - so you want to confirm it is really a misspelling or a valid phrase?

Comment: I am aware that it is frequently a misspelling of "in principle". I want to know whether it has ever had a valid use.

Comment: @TomHosker - a valid use in what sense? With the same meaning of “in principle”?

Comment: With a meaning distinct from "in principle". There's a whole warren of weird English phrases - I think coming from Norman French - which begin with "in": "in gross", "in ordinary", "in chief". I was wondering if "in principal" was ever one of them - perhaps meaning something similar to "in chief".

Comment: If not, an elegant alternative would be awesome.

Comment: @TomHosker - the problem is what you mean by “elegant”. You should probably ask on Writing SE